# rsyslog conditional RepeatedMsgReduction

Tags: configuration, postfix-mta, rsyslog

I need to deactivate RepeatedMsgReduction on my Linux server to allow fail2ban to evaluate every failed login attempt. (See this bug report: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=440037)

As I don't want to flood my log files, I would love to have that feature only on those logfiles that fail2ban scans, especially mail.warn.

Is there a way to set a conditional rule/filter in rsyslog.conf that sets

```
$RepeatedMsgReduction = off
```

iff the message is bound to mail.warn?

Answer (score 14):

Ok, reading the manual and docs again and again now brought me to the solution:

Reading http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html tells you, that the directive

```
$RepeatedMsgReduction off
```

remains valid until the next directive is specified.

This means, if you want all messages of mail.warn, but want reduced messages in all others (mail.info and mail.err), change the configuration to look like this (assuming, that message reduction is globally turned on):

```
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
$RepeatedMsgReduction off
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
$RepeatedMsgReduction on
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err
```

With this, mail.warn will contain all messages logged, while the other log levels (and files) will contain the famous "last message repeated n times" lines. This allows e.g. fail2ban to examine mail.warn for evil activities, while the other log files stay "clean".

Answer (score 5):

I appreciate the research provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20555451/5025060) showing how to selectively disable rsyslog message reduction.  However, I think it important to recognize that there are arguments in favor of **disabling reduction entirely**.

**Background:**

Syslog's *MARK* facility is intended to provide evidence that syslog (and by inference the server itself) is running by periodically logging an entry as:

`Sep  5 11:41:28 servername rsyslogd: -- MARK --`

I came to this SO question because message reduction was defeating the purpose of *MARK* by aggregating my mark messages:

`Sep  5 12:33:46 servername rsyslogd: message repeated 48 times: [-- MARK --]`

I.e., the above message is logged in *lieu* of 48 periodic messages, nullifying their utility as tracking information.

**Analysis:**

Initially I therefore planned to disable reduction only for *MARK* messages.  However, having read [this article](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/action/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html) I am inclined to turn off *RepeatedMsgReduction* entirely:

> - While turning this feature on can save some space in logs, most log analysis tools need to see the repeated messages, they can’t handle
>     the “last message repeated” format.
> - This is a feature that worked decades ago when logs were small and reviewed by a human, it fails badly on high volume logs processed by
>     tools.

**Conclusion:**

I recommend simply disabling reduction.  Why?  Now that disk space is inexpensive and we rely increasingly on automated tools like [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org), the benefit of reduction is outweighed by the costs of configuration complexity and information loss.